# How to make an exe file through my software in vb6

Tags: vb6, exe, builder

Can somebody help me here.

I am working on a program in visual basic 6. I want my program to make an exe file when user adds or choose his options.

For eg -- take an example of RAT or keyloggers. Users choose what they want and when they click build server, a exe file is created, with the name server

I also want that when a user click on build, my software creates a .exe file

I want a right direction to start from. Please somebody direct me.

Comment: Sounds like a request for assistance creating malware.

Comment: i just gave an example, i am not actually creating a malware. It was a best example i could give. If you could help me please tell.

Comment: @MarkHurd , Ill try it out. Looks like you gave me a correct direction to work on. I think i now i cant make my project. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For VB6 I'd suggest creating the exe separately, using an .ini or .config file for configuration, adding it as a resource.

When the exe is needed, extract if from the resources and make the .ini or .config file with the configuration needed.